# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

```
if personal_id == nil {

        if let err = SD.executeChange("INSERT INTO personal_info(user_id, fname, lname, gender, dob, country_code, phone, created_at) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", withArgs: [email, fname, lname, gender, date, country_code, phone, strDate]) {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Table"
                alert.message = "Error inserting"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
        } else{
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Table"
            alert.message = "successfully inserted"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }
    } else {
        if let err_update = SD.executeChange("UPDATE personal_info SET fname = ?, lname = ?, gender = ?, dob = ?, country_code = ?, phone = ?, updated_at = ? WHERE personal_info_id = ?", withArgs: [fname, lname, gender, date, country_code, phone, strDate, personal_id!]) {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Table"
                alert.message = "Error updating"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
        } else {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Table"
                alert.message = "Record updated"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
        }
    }
```

I have recently updated to Xcode 7.0.1 from 6.4. Now I am having a lot of errors. This code shows an error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

in the place of `withArgs`: []

Here's `executeChange` method signature:

```
public static func executeChange(sqlStr: String, withArgs: [AnyObject]) -> Int?
```

Comment: What are the function parameters for the `executeChange` call? And what are the types for email, fname, lname, gender, date, country_code, phone, and strDate?

Comment: withArgs[] is of anyObject type and the remaining name,name,gender,date,etc., are string

Comment: I am using the swift data framework

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that all the types you're sending in withArgs[] are Strings? no optionals? no value types? (you can easily see the type of the variable by using Alt+Click on variable name)

Comment: use like withArgs: ["\(email)","\(fname)","\(lname)","\(gender)","\(date)","\(country_code)","\(phone)","\(strDate)"]

Comment: most of them are string optionals and then NSdate() and strings @Vladimir Kofman

Comment: @Rizwan Sheikh when i tried to do that i got an error saying **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(_builtinStringLiteral: RawPointer, byteSize: Word, isASCII: Int1)' (aka '(_builtinStringLiteral: Builtin.RawPointer, byteSize: Builtin.Word, isASCII: Builtin.Int1)')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `withArgs` method parameter defined as

```
withArgs: [AnyObject]
```

you can't have `Optionals` in that array. To make it work you'll have to unwrap them first.